# Multiple Image Gallery on a Single Page

Tags: jquery

Could you please help to use multiple image gallery on my page based on the code below. It works fine if only one gallery is on the page, in other case I have to copy the code two times and give different IDs to the elements. I believe that there is a much better solution.

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div class="img">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="images/1.png">
        <img src="images/2.png">
        <img src="images/3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/1_tb.png">
        <img src="images/2_tb.png">
        <img src="images/3_tb.png">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="img">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="images/1.png">
        <img src="images/2.png">
        <img src="images/3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/1_tb.png">
        <img src="images/2_tb.png">
        <img src="images/3_tb.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){
$(".image img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
$(".thumbnail img").click(function(e){
        var $this = $(this),
        index = $this.index();
    $(".image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to handle galleries separately, changing something only in gallery where clicked thumbnail is placed, using, for example, `.closest()` to find gallery main wrapper:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0a6km5zc/).

JS:

```
$(function()
{
    $(".image").each(function()
    {
        $(this).find('img:not(:first)').hide();
    });

    $(".thumbnail img").on("click", function()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        var index = $this.index();
        var gallery = $this.closest('.img');
        gallery.find(".image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, selecting by class name will find all qualifying elements in the DOM. Hence, your gallery's are not independent of each other.

You need a mechanism for constraining the selections to each particular gallery.

Your code can be refactored as a jQuery plugin ...

```
//jQuery plugin
$.fn.myGallery = function() {
    this.each(function(i, gallery) {
        $(".image img:eq(0)", gallery).nextAll().hide();
        $(".thumbnail img", gallery).click(function(e) {
            $(".image img", gallery).eq($(this).index()).show().siblings().hide();
        });
    });
}
```

... and invoked on all containers with `class == "img"`

```
$(".img").myGallery();
```

Personally, I would change classname "img" to "gallery" and invoke the plugin with :

```
$(".gallery").myGallery();
```